# Why does Rebuild ALL Fail after moving solution folder to a different location?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-applications

I have a C# web application that I've been working on which has built properly since I began working with it.  I moved the entire solution into a different folder, and now, when I try to build it says "Rebuild All failed" with no other errors.  I have reviewed the verbose output from build; but, I don't see anything that jumps out at me as causing the problem.  If I move the solution back to the original location, it will build again.  Anyone know why the new location breaks the build?

Thanks.

Comment: there should be an error in the `output` console

Comment: As mentioned above, there isn't anything clearly indicating an error.  I'd post it here; but, it's too long for a comment or question.

Comment: I should also note that MSBuild from the command line completes properly and I can debug if I manually build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I found it- turns out, moving it several directories deeper may have blown the maximum path size for NTFS (see this question: [VS2010 - same soltuion (IE SVN checkout), different locations, one builds, one fails any ideas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773998/vs2010-same-soltuion-ie-svn-checkout-different-locations-one-builds-one-f)). I moved my project to a root directory in c: and now it's compiling normally in VS2010.

A friendlier error would have been nice; but, hey, what can you do?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause of this error is that the location you are moving the solution to is not trusted.

For example, if you move the solution to a protected folder like `C:\Program Files` or `C:\Windows` or a network location.

If this is not the case, please advise where you are moving the file too and perhaps share any errors from your build log.

Comment: I have a workspace under my documents folder, and I've just moved it into a "Branch" folder under there:


For example, moved from 


%USERPROFILE%/Documents/Workspace/DOTNET/TheSolutionInQuestion


to


%USERPROFILE%/Documents/Workspace/DOTNET/ProjectName/BranchName/TheSolutionInQuestion

Comment: In this case, I suspect you have path reliance in your solution somewhere. When you open the solution are all projects present? You can edit solution files and project files in Notepad or similar - it is worth checking for relative paths that may have been broken.

Comment: I think I have it.  I don't have enough rep to post the answer for another 7 hours; but, I will then.

I believe I found it- turns out, moving it several directories deeper may have blown the maximum path size for NTFS (see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773998/vs2010-same-soltuion-ie-svn-checkout-different-locations-one-builds-one-f).  

I moved my project to a root directory in c: and now it's compiling normally in VS2010.  A friendlier error would have been nice; but, hey, what can you do?